# "Gentle confines"

Tags: etymology, phrases, idioms, phrase-origin

Where does this phrase come from?  It's something I use (usually ironically) and something that's "just there" in my lexicon like "fit as a fiddle".  However when I Google it, no origin pops up.  It is used as early as [1855](https://books.google.com/books?id=OTUFAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA85&lpg=PA85&dq=%22gentle%20confines%22%20origin&source=bl&ots=0iCuFskwga&sig=ACfU3U1lp3e0teevFFBEe7HwtoQVYUNMFQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjQ2vjqs4XlAhULbKwKHUMMC6kQ6AEwBHoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22gentle%20confines%22%20origin&f=false):

> It is in his admiration for the gentle confines between virtue and her antagonist

This occurrence is 164 years old.  A commenter below has used Google Ngrams to source "the  confines_noun" to around 1650, so 369 years old (earlier if you make the search case insensitive).

It is obvious what it means.  It has become a kind of frequently used phrase, [idiomatic expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idiom), [trope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trope_(literature)) or [formulaic language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formulaic_language).

In ironic use it refers to a place which is not gentle at all. So a phrase which lends itself to ironic use, like "your humble servant".  It would be great if it turned out to be a phrase first used by Shakespeare or the like.

Comment: The one example you've cited strikes me as "unusual", compared to other written instances of the sequence [**the gentle confines**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+gentle+confines%22) - which are nearly always followed by ***of** [something that gently confines / restrains someone or something]*. In fact, I'm not quite sure how to interpret the usage when followed by ***between virtue and her antagonist***. Maybe it's become something of a "fixed expression" now, but it's really just ordinary English.

Comment: The expression that has really taken off in the past 60 years or so is "[friendly confines](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=friendly+confines%2Cgentle+confines&year_start=1850&year_end=2005&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfriendly%20confines%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgentle%20confines%3B%2Cc0)," an expression that has become something close to a cliché among U.S. baseball fans. It refers to a home ballpark—particularly one that is relatively small and "hitter friendly."

Comment: @FumbleFingers my answer may seem unusual because it is 164 years old.  My point in quoting it was simply that it was 164 years old: I am trying to date the first occurrence of the expression.  It is obvious what it means.  However it has become a kind of frequently used phrase (I'm also searching for a word for "frequently used phrase".  A trope?).  In ironic use it refers to a place which is not gentle at all.  So I'm interested in first occurrence, for example if it is a phrase in Shakespeare or the like.

Comment: [Google Ngrams' results are rather startling.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+_ADJ_+confines_NOUN&year_start=1600&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20_ADJ_%20confines_NOUN%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: NICE!  So it starts in 1650?

Comment: no, not necessarily, Ngrams just hardly indexes anything before that and drops out completely below 1500

Comment: @AndrewLeach: I don't know what *your* NGram is telling us, but [this one](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+gentle+confines&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20gentle%20confines%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cthe%20gentle%20confines%3B%2Cc0) suggests the specific (unexceptional, imho) sequence ***gentle confines*** only really started to gain "currency" around WW2. With just 2 cited instances over the years 1900 to 1946. But personally I think it's not really a collocation for which it's meaningful to look for a "first citation" anyway...

Comment: ...(I just can't think of any defensible text to accompany a closevote for "pointless search" :)

Comment: How about "within the gentle confines of meaningful discourse, your humble servant personally adheres to the belief that this search is aimless and inconsequential"?

Answer (score 1):

Searches for "gentle confines" in the Google Books, Elephind, and Hathi Trust databases yielded just 14 confirmed matches prior to 1980, none earlier that the 1855 instance that the poster found in Google Books. Here is the entire set of pre-1980 matches, in chronological order.

From a [review of James Hannay, *Satire and Satirists*](https://books.google.com/books?id=OTUFAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA85&dq=%22gentle+confines%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj2l6XGtNX0AhVQV80KHbjBDCcQ6AF6BAgJEAI#v=onepage&q=%22gentle%20confines%22&f=false), in *The Illustrated London Magazine* (1855):

> The author's appreciation of Horace as a man seems to us, on the whole, just ;  and certainly it is hard to reconcile the character so judged with our notions of the real poetical spirit. But as a moralist, Horace does not seem deserving of immense respect, though as a satirist he is very pleasant. Hi objections to vice do not arise from any preference for an exalted system of morals ; and if he he is anywhere very much in earnest, it is in his admiration for the **gentle confines** between virtue and her antagonist ; a spirit which speaks very sweetly in some of the easier and lesser odes.

From "[A Letter from Bill's Stomach to Bill's Mother](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=uiuo.ark:/13960/t9669385v&view=1up&seq=276&skin=2021&q1=%22gentle%20confines%22)," dated November 16, 1902, in *The Plexus* (1902):

> Dear Madam: — It is now nearly two months since your son Bill brought me from the sweet and **gentle confines** of your culinary department to do battle with the restaurant chefs who operate upon the gastro-intestinal tract of medical students. It is past midnight, and while Bill is sleeping unusually well, I have siezed his pen in my sphincter pylori and take the liberty of relating my experiences since your delicate custard pies have be- come only a memory.

From Arthur Johnson, "[National Western Live Stock Show, 1920](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=uc1.$b232642&view=1up&seq=359&q1=%22gentle%20confines%22)," in *Through the Leaves* (December 1919):

> The live stock exhibits, in fact, promise to strain the capacity of the show buildings now provided. Echoes from the Royal at Kansas City and the International at Chicago carry warnings of a genuine rush of pure breeders to pose their animals in a show reserve where East meets West—where the strains from the uplands of the Rockies mix with those from the **gentle confines** of the Missouri and further eastward.

From an [unidentified article](https://books.google.com/books?id=j_YKAQAAMAAJ&q=%22gentle+confines%22&dq=%22gentle+confines%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj2l6XGtNX0AhVQV80KHbjBDCcQ6AF6BAgIEAI) in *Motion Picture* magazine (1931) [snippet view]:

> A seeming promise of happiness was held out to her [Dolores Del Rio] when, a girl in Mexico City, Jaime Del Rio offered himself as a husband. She did not love Del Rio. She did not know what love was. She did not know what life was. Just out of the **gentle confines** of a convent, she cared for this suitor only as a young girl cares for an older man who has been good to her.

From an [unidentified item](https://books.google.com/books?newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&id=8rnmAAAAMAAJ&dq=%22gentle+confines%22&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=treat) in *Rutgers Alumni Monthly* (January 1945) [combined snippets]:

> The front line medic is the boy who should get a lot of credit when the final roll has been taken on this war. We are far from the front line, but we have seen the treatment these medics have given the wounded before they reached the **gentle confines** of a general hospital. It has been really remarkable.

From J.C. Penney, [*View from the Ninth Decade*](https://books.google.com/books?newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&id=rbFIAAAAYAAJ&dq=%22material+gains+but+the+rewards+that+come+through%22&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22Self-expression+is+excellent%22) (1960) [combined snippets]:

> Self-expression is excellent when maintained within the **gentle confines** of the greater good of the family and society; when children, or adults for that matter, forget this, society is threatened.

From John Knox, "[Busy Week for Tourney Bridge](https://cdnc.ucr.edu/cgi-bin/cdnc?a=d&d=CJ19630131.2.33&e=-------en--20--1--txt-txIN-%252522gentle+confines%252522-------1)," in the *Coronado [California] Eagle and Journal* (January 31, 1963):

> It was a busy week for Coronado duplicate bridge players. Four games including a Unit Winners Game was held. Large turnouts continued indicating that the **gentle confines** of the Coronado Unit of the ACBL are conducive to continued interest in this exciting sport.

From an [unidentified article](https://books.google.com/books?id=0fomAQAAIAAJ&q=%22gentle+confines%22&dq=%22gentle+confines%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiptM6uvdX0AhVRK80KHShsAiE4ChDoAXoECAIQAg) in in *Horizon* magazine (1967) [combined snippets]:

> Athletes take books along on trips and use the "enemy's" library; according to one coach, just as they are better students as seniors than they are as sophomores, the seniors on the team are worse athletes than they were in their sophomore year. The teams, even within the **gentle confines** of the once mighty Ivy League, generally do not do very well. The squads are small, because students will not go out for a sport only to sit on the bench and be mincemeat for the varsity; the common philosophy is, "Either I play on the varsity or I quit."

From William Shelton, [*Stowaway to the Moon: The Camelot Odyssey*](https://books.google.com/books?id=ZNPlJ3-m34wC&q=%22gentle+confines%22&dq=%22gentle+confines%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjEv9invdX0AhVhdc0KHbISA_wQ6AF6BAgIEAI) (1973) [combined snippets]:

> "Ben," Rick said as he floated up, "your turn to sleep. I'll spell you now on the watch."
>
> E.J. felt his tired body gratefully relax beneath the **gentle confines** of the straps. He felt better than at any moment since he'd been discovered; at least the commander had spoken decently to him for the first time.

From an [unidentified article](https://books.google.com/books?id=J6NLAQAAMAAJ&q=%22gentle+confines%22&dq=%22gentle+confines%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjEv9invdX0AhVhdc0KHbISA_wQ6AF6BAgCEAI) in *Wyoming Wildlife* (1973 or 1974) [snippet view]:

> ...generals on their heels and send them scampering for more **gentle confines**. In the form of a time-worn cliché, game and fish departments are now and eternally hereafter in the dynamic but exasperating people business. The business of public service.

From Timothy Webb, [*The Violet in the Crucible: Shelley and Translation*](https://books.google.com/books?id=GfsNAAAAIAAJ&q=%22gentle+confines%22&dq=%22gentle+confines%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjEv9invdX0AhVhdc0KHbISA_wQ6AF6BAgKEAI) (1976) [combined snippets]:

> For another, the rest of what Silva has to say qualifies his first statement very significantly: Calderón is the poet of the starry skies, of trim gardens, sweet purling streams, crystalline fountains and multi-coloured flowers. His is the refined, delicate Nature of the court poet, accustomed to move within the **gentle confines** of surroundings entirely artificial.'

From an [unidentified article](https://books.google.com/books?id=uqcVAQAAIAAJ&q=%22gentle+confines%22&dq=%22gentle+confines%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjEv9invdX0AhVhdc0KHbISA_wQ6AF6BAgDEAI) in *The Art World: A Seventy-Five-Year Treasury of ARTnews* (1978):

> How much this humble worker dreamed of ultimate success I do not know. Most likely being a good bourgeois, his thoughts were easily enraptured and seldom roamed beyond the **gentle confines** of a contented French point of view. Perhaps it is just as well that the honors that now crowd in upon him were not his during his own day, for they might have dimmed the altogether charming simplicity and force of his art.

From an [unidentified article](https://books.google.com/books?newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&id=unJYAAAAYAAJ&dq=%22gentle+confines%22&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22even+those+called+states%22) in *Annual Forum* (1978) [combined snippets]:

> In the western world, the images evoked by words like *central authority* at once run afoul of a rich litany of individualistic values that warn us to be wary of resting a case at that extreme. We are suspicious of organizations, even those called states, if the organizations are allowed to infringe the freedom of individual citizens to arrange their own affairs within the **gentle confines** of society's legislated or commonly held norms of social behavior.

And from an [unidentified article](https://books.google.com/books?id=gl02AQAAIAAJ&q=%22gentle+confines%22&dq=%22gentle+confines%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjEv9invdX0AhVhdc0KHbISA_wQ6AF6BAgJEAI) in *Redbook* magazine (1979) [text not visible in snippet window]:

> Outside the **gentle confines** of Maine, Ramona knew, the world was very different: strange, dangerous—thrilling!

Three of the matches come from 1855–1919; two from 1931–1945; two from 1960–1967; and six from 1973–1979. This is not the profile of a long-established idiomatic phrase.

Here is an Ngram chart mapping the frequency of occurrence of the phrase during the period 1850–2010:

[image]

And here, by way of contrast, is an Ngram chart mapping that same frequency (in blue) against the frequency of "friendly confines" (in red) over the same period:

[image]

As I noted two years ago in a comment beneath the posted question, "friendly confines" really has become something of a catchphrase or idiomatic expression in U.S. sports (referring to a team's home field, park, court, or stadium) during the past 60 hears or so, whereas "gentle confines" remains comparatively rare and shows very little or no sustained growth in frequency over the past half-century.

In my opinion, "gentle confines" is only marginally—if at all—a "frequently used phrase, idiomatic expression, trope, or formulaic language." Its occurrence in 1855 seems not to reflect widespread contemporaneous popular use, but rather to represent an exceptionally early instance of a formulation that even today is not especially common.

Comment: With regard to the OP's allusion to a possible instance of "gentle confines" from "around 1650," the Ngram that prompted that suggestion seems to involve not the specific phrase "gentle confines," but rather the occurrence of "confines" as a noun preceded by "the" and any adjective—that is, any phrase of the form "the [adjective] confines." I found no evidence that an instance of "the gentle confines" appeared in print around 1650 or indeed at any time before 1855.